# Angular Ionic CSS not being applied

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on an Ionic and Angular project.  I just can't figure out how to control the padding on elements wrapped around ion-item.  I've looked at several solutions and none seem to work:

I have looked at both of these rsources and I can't get my spacing to reflect my stylesheets.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#content-space

[Why Ionic 5 content padding is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199972/why-ionic-5-content-padding-is-not-working)

For example I have the following:

```
              <ion-col size-lg="8" class="ion-padding">
                <ion-item lines="none">
                  <ion-label >{{stat.playerDisplayName}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
              </ion-col>
              
              <ion-col size-lg="2" class="ion-padding">
                <ion-item lines="none">
                  <ion-label>{{stat.goals}}</ion-label>
                </ion-item>
              </ion-col>
```

I have tried the following but nothing changes on my file:

```
  ion-padding {
    padding: 0px;
  }

  ion-padding {
    --ion-padding: 0px;
  }
```

I have tried using the official documentation also but to no avail.  I did `ionic -v` and it shows 6.10.0.  I looked at my package file and I see the following:

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0"
```

What am I missing?

Here is my full code:

HTML FILE

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" class="ion-text-center no-padding">
  <ion-col>
    <ion-item>
      <h5>{{product.productName}}</h5>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
<ion-row>

    <ion-col>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedProductId">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-select-option value="">Select Product</ion-select-option>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let product of Products">
            <ion-select-option [value]="product.productId">{{product.productName}}</ion-select-option>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>

</ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-button color="success" (click)="onAddProduct()">
      Add Product
    </ion-button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

CSS FILE

```
.no-padding{
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ion-col padding to 0 using below way. Its so simple. **Remove classes which you have added.**

```
ion-row>ion-col {
   padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Try with !important property. If that not work try to give below class in css and use the same in HTML.

```
.padding-zero {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I am using same in my project and its working for me. Can you create stackblitz so I can check what went wrong.

Comment: I added more code for exactly what I'm trying to do.  This line I added is where I want my rows to not have any padding: `class="ion-text-center no-padding"`. This seems like it should be so straight forward but I just can't get it to work.  I also tried to center my text in the row, but no luck using the ionic suggested way of doing it.

Comment: Create stackblitz

Comment: I tried, but I don't see and angular ionic option in there. Only plain angular and that does not have any stylesheet template. In any case here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-awjkrm?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts.  I simply want to be able to control the padding between those rows.